# Почему конкатенация строк - это точка, а не плюс?

Tags: php

Возьмем 5 различных языков:

[Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377768/string-concatenation-in-ruby)

[Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-the-preferred-way-to-concatenate-a-string-in-python)

[JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696632/best-way-to-concatenate-strings-in-javascript)

[C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319859/how-to-concatenate-two-strings-in-c)

[Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753869/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-java)

Всех их объединяет то, что в наличии оператор '+' для конкатенации строк. Этот оператор логичен - хотим сложить две строки - складываем. Я битый час пытался понять, почему код `echo "str" + " yolo"` возвращает `0`, а не то, что я хочу и мои муки разрешились только потрясающим открытием, что конкатенация - это оператор '.' Как создатели языка объясняют такой финт? Какие причины замены устоявшегося оператора?

Comment: Мне кажется нет смысла на этом заострять внимание. Нужно просто об этом помнить.....Ибо так можно о любом ЯП спросить. Почему в С++ пишут `cout << 2002;` или почему в том или ином языке `elif`  вместо `elseif` и т.д.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Все очень просто. Когда то очень давно php был написан на перл. Грубо говоря, php был просто шаблонизатор для perl. И поэтому, оттудова и пришли многие "особенности". В перле принята на первый взгляд странная, но вполне логичная система. Не операнды определяют операцию, а операция. То есть, '+' складывает числа. И если в переменных не числа, то они будут преобразованы к ним. Точно также, '.' - это конкатенация строк (если быть педантом, то строки складывать нельзя). И операция '.' по надобности преобразует операнды в строки и конкатенирует.

P.S. Сейчас в php притащили оператор "летающая тарелка" - `<=>`, который в perl был годами:)

Comment: Для тех, кто не знал про «летающую тарелку»: [тыц](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php); а вот в русской версии документации ([клац](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php)) пока ещё не написали ...

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в php можно делать операции над строками как с числами. А значит что операции сложения чисел и конкатенации нужно как то различать. Правда это я так считаю :)
Например:

```
$first = "9";
$second = "1";
$a . $b; // 91
$a + $b; // 10
```

В вашем случае `echo "str" + " yolo"` -> оба текста были приведены к числу - в этом случае к нулю. Ну и результат вы получили соответствующий.